# Creative User Names for Test/Dev Accounts

Tags: user-accounts, testing, development-enviroment

I need creative help thinking of clever and creative User names to make up for Test accounts....aaaannd go!

Comment: what type of testing you want to do? level of testing? could you please share the scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use the accounts from Contoso. The names are realistic and good to remember. Even for a non native english speaker like me.

You can create the accounts automatically with the script from here:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Create-Contoso-Users-in-3e2f38f2

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 test accounts

tasharepoint1
tasharepoint2
tasharepoint3

TA stands for "test account".  Not sure how creative this is, but it has been working well for me for years.

Bob